# Grayed Toobar Button

Tags: button, mfc, toolbar

I added a button to a toolbar and when I run the application, it is grayed (desactivated) I could not click on it. I tried to add events when I click on it, but still gray.

How could I make it active?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there's a handler for the button. MFC will automatically disable a button if there's no ON_COMMAND handler for it.

Otherwise you need to implement `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` to enable the button.

Comment: I already did it but still grayed. The only way i found to make it not gray is 

       cToolBar.GetToolBarCtrl().EnableButton(ID_NEW_FOLDER, true);

but when i clik on it nothing happen (I worte code but nothing works).

Comment: Ok it works now, I had to add the ID into tha Accelerator table, weired but it worked at least.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it works now, I had to add the ID into tha Accelerator table, weired but it worked at least.